# Dynamically generate textblocks

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using Windows Phone Panorama App template and using LongListSelector to allow users to click and view the details of the item listed in the Long list. The details of the items is available in the DetailsPage.xaml. 
My code is working fine i.e users are able to jump to the right item on DetailsPage.xaml and the content is visible to them.

```
                <!--new text block -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_1}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_1}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}"  Margin="10,0,0,20" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_2}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_2}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" Margin="10,0,0,20"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_3}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_3}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" Margin="10,0,0,20"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_4}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_4}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" Margin="10,0,0,20"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_5}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_5}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" Margin="10,0,0,20"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term_6}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition_6}" Style="{StaticResource Textblock}" Margin="10,0,0,20"/>
```

---

My problem is with how the items on the DetailsPage.xaml is displayed. For instance, if Option 1 on the Longlistselector has 4 items, and Option 2 has six items, Option 2 appears fine, but Option 1 has lot of spaces in the end (possibly coming out of the no data for Term 5, and Term 6). If there is another Option 3 with just 1 items, the whole DetailsPage contains lot of blank spaces after displaying the single item. I have more than 100 items in some of the Options, and the unwanted extra spaces at the end of the DetailsPage is simply annoying. I would like to know if there's anyway to generate the formatted Textblocks along with the binded resources in the DetailsPage dynamically so that the extra white spaces can be removed? If not, how can I show only the required Textblocks for a given Option?

**Update:** This is how the data is loaded in the textblocks:

```
public void LoadData()
        {


            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "0",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1", 

Term_2 = "This is a term2",
        Definition_2 = "This definition2",

Term_3 = "This is a term3",
        Definition_3 = "This definition3",

Term_4 = "This is a term4",
        Definition_4 = "This definition4",

Term_5 = "This is a term5",
        Definition_5 = "This definition5",

});

this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "1",`enter code here`
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 1",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 1"

});
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "2",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 2",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 2"

});
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "3",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 3",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 3"

});
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "4",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 4",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 4"

});
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "5",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 5",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 5"

});

this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()

{
    ID = "6",
    Term_1 = "This is a term1 for ID 6",
    Definition_1 = "This definition1 for ID 6"

});
```

If I select any textblock, I will get the terms and definitions listed in the respective ID of the Texblock. If I select first Textblock, I will get the Terms/definitions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If I select another textblock, I will get only one term/definition.

This is how it is exactly coming in the output. The problem is that Textblock for terms 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 introduces blank spaces if there are no terms to display for that ID. So, the empty textblocks are eating up the spaces on the screen. I would like the Detailspage to render only the TextBlocks which are applicable for an ID and then stop creating them for the remaining blocks for that ID.

Comment: Can you add some additional code and xaml, possibly with some screenshots of what goes wrong and how you want it? The problem description hints to "DataTemplate" as part of the answer, but in this very condensed form it's very difficult to see what exactly it is you want.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: added more info about the problem

Comment: I can see where you're going, and what your problem is, but it's scope is too big to explain in a reasonably sized answer, so I'll leave some hints as a comment: Instead of defining "Term_1" through "Term_2" as fixed properties, define them as one List-of-Terms property on ItemViewModel, containing as many "Terms" as you need. Then you can bind that list to an ItemsControl, which will take up as much space as it needs to display the items. So instead of pre-defining six TextBlocks, you can use a ListView (or something like that), and bind to the list of terms.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: Do you have any example that I can explore to understand the implementation?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: I found this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853276/wpf-list-of-viewmodels-bound-to-list-of-model-objects. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Short on time, but I wrote up an answer that (hopefully) explains what I mean. Upon rereading the question, I think your scenario is not as complicated as I first thought it was. If I find time (and if the answer should not suffice), I'll elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining "Term_1" through "Term_2" as properties on `ItemViewModel`, declare a List property on `ItemViewModel` (I'm assuming of type string here):

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    // ... other properties
    public List<string> Terms
    {
       get; set; // Implementation ommited
    }
}
```

Creation of ItemViewModel instances would then become something like

```
ItemViewModel viewModelItem= new ItemViewModel() { Id = "1", Definition_1 = "..." };
viewModelItem.Terms.Add("Term1 for Id1");
viewModelItem.Terms.Add("Term2 for Id1");
viewModelItem.Terms.Add("Term3 for Id1");
// ...as many terms as you have...
this.Items.Add(viewModelItem);
```

In your detail page, which I assume shows one `ItemViewModel` (the selected one from the `LongListSelector`), you can add a `ListView` (or something similar) in XAML and bind it to the Terms property of the `ItemViewModel` class:

```
<!-- Assumes an `ItemViewModel` instance is the `DataContext` for the ListView! -->
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Terms}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `ListView` will generate as many `ListViewItems` as necessary.